# Angular 2 router navigate to url but still rendering the source component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create an authentication system with Angular 2, i used angular2-jwt and everything works fine, but the problem i'm having is when an Unauthenticated user tries to acces a restricted route, to handle this i check if the user is authenticated in the ngOnInit() function, if not, the user should be redirected to the login page, in my case, the url changes, but it still renders the acced component template, here's my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

import {UserService} from "../services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: '../templates/home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/styles/home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

full_name: string;
constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router){}

ngOnInit() {
  if(this.userService.isTokenExpired()){
    this.router.navigate([''])
  }else{
    this.userService.getSessionData()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          let usrData = data.data.user;
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(usrData));
          this.full_name = usrData.firstname+" "+usrData.lastname;
          if(usrData.role == 'admin'){
            this.router.navigate(['admin']);
          }
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

here's how it looks:

[image]
You can notice that there's no data.

the weired thing is that the same code in another Component (the AdminComponent) works fine.

here's my **app.routes.ts** file:

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";

import {AdminComponent} from "./components/admin.component";
import {LoginComponent} from "./components/login.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./components/home.component";
import {GroupsComponent} from "./components/groups.component";
import {TpComponent} from "./components/tps.component";
import {TraineeComponent} from "./components/trainee.component";
import {RegisterComponent} from "./components/register.component";
import {HometpsComponent} from "./components/hometps.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
    { path: '',
      redirectTo: '/admin/tps',
      pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'tps', component: TpComponent},
    { path: 'groupes', component: GroupsComponent},
    { path: 'stagiaires', component: TraineeComponent}
  ]},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    { path: '',
      redirectTo: '/home/tps',
      pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'tps', component: HometpsComponent},
  ]},
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent}
];
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which path you want it to go to? I don't see the url change in the screenshot

Comment: thanks for your replay, it already changed, i typed **http://localhost:4200/home** the url changed into **http://localhost:4200** but the template loaded is the one for HomeComponent, i just did some debugging and i found out that the router throws the Error : **Cannot activate an already activated outlet**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my routing was working perfectly, the problem was in my child component HometpsComponent's ngOnInit() where i was reading data from localStorage (which is empty if the user is not logged in or if his session has expired) which generates an error and prevents the router to navigate.

thank you.